# How to get items from itemized environment

Tags: macros

Briefly: suppose I have a file containing

```
\begin{itemize}
  \item pluto
  \item pippo
  \item caio
  ...
\end{itemize}
```

and I would like this to be equivalet to

```
\def\fitstitem{pluto}
\def\seconditem{pippo}
\def\thirditem{caio}
 ...
```

et cetera. How can I do that?

More precisely, here my actual true problem: 
I have latex program for creating random quiz from a database of exercises. The   database is of this form

```
 \newes
  \textexer{here the thext of the question} 
  \possexer{possible proposed answers to the question}% in form like "a) first option, b) second option, c) third option, d) fourth option"}
  \correctanswer{correct answer} % in the form like \correctanswer{c}
```

Now, I have a database that works for moodle, which is build that way

```
 \begin{multi}[points=2,penalty=1]{} 
 text of the question
 \item first answer
 \item second answer
 \item*  third answer 
 \item fourth answer
 \end{multi}
```

where the * marks the correct answer. I would like to be able to use the moodle format in my routine, for that I need to extract the text of the question as well as all possibilities and the information of which answer is correct. Basically I would like the latter itemized commads to be equivalent to the former list of commands (\textexer...)

I tried to redefine the ambien "multi" but I did not succed to extact the parts I need.

Comment: it's possible, but it would be easier if you changed the syntax with `\newcommand\myitem[1]{\item #1}`  then `\myitem{first answer} \myitem{second answer}...`  as then all you need to do is redefine myitem to save its argument

Comment: I agree, but the databases I have in my hands are in that form,

Comment: Ok I was just checking via a comment if that was acceptable, if not that's fine (just that the answers need to be a bit harder:-)

Comment: It seems that this question has been completely answered here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/540232/how-to-use-getitems-latex-package/540235?noredirect=1#540235