# How to use getitems LaTeX package?

Tags: macros, packages, itemize

I need to extract the body and items from an itemized ambient like

```
 \begin{itemize}
  HERE THE BODY
   \item first item
   \item second item
   ...
 \end{itemize}
```

I've been told that package getitems does the job. But I'm not able to use it. Which are the commands for 
1) extracting the body text, and 
2) extracting and sorting items?

Comment: relatet question (or, if you prefer, my actual problem): https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/539633/how-to-get-items-from-itemized-environment?noredirect=1#comment1363277_539633

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way with `listofitems`.

LIMITATIONS: ignores blank items; does not allow for optional argument on `\item`.

Sorting is another issue.  You haven't really specified what you mean by it.

Let me know if you *also*  wanted to print them out at the time of invocation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listofitems,environ}
\NewEnviron{itemizesave}{%
  \setsepchar{\item}%
  \ignoreemptyitems
  \greadlist*\myitem{\BODY}%
}
\begin{document}
 \begin{itemizesave}
   \item first item
   \item second item

   ...
   \item the last item
 \end{itemizesave}

My first item is ``\myitem[1]''.

Then I have ``\myitem[2]''.

The list length is \myitemlen, so the final item I have is ``\myitem[3]''.
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**SUPPLEMENT**

The OP directed me to another question that further amplifies the problem, including question text before the first `\item` and the signifying of a correct answer with a `*` following the `\item`.

Here is a solution to that problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listofitems,environ}
\NewEnviron{itemizesave}{%
  \setsepchar{\item/*}%
  \greadlist*\myitem{\BODY}%
  \gdef\theanswer{0}%
  \foreachitem\z\in\myitem[]{%
    \ifnum\listlen\myitem[\zcnt]>1\relax
      \xdef\theanswer{\the\numexpr\zcnt-1}\fi
  }%
  \xdef\numberofchoices{\the\numexpr\myitemlen-1\relax}
}
\newcommand\thequestion{\myitem[1]}
\def\thechoice[#1]{\edef\tmp{\listlen\myitem[1+#1]}%
  \myitem[1+#1,\tmp]}
\begin{document}
 \begin{itemizesave}
text of question
   \item first choice
   \item* second choice
   \item the last choice
 \end{itemizesave}

The question is ``\thequestion''.

My first choice is ``\thechoice[1]''.

Then I have ``\thechoice[2]''.

The number of choices is \numberofchoices, so 
the final choice I have is ``\thechoice[3]''.

The correct answer is choice \theanswer.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great, thak you. Actually my real problem I'm trying to solve is this one https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/539633/how-to-get-items-from-itemized-environment?noredirect=1#comment1363277_539633 which is slightly more complicated but your answer helps a lot!

Comment: by the way is there a way to extract also the body berfore first item?

Comment: To your first comment @user126154, the `listofitems` can do nested searching, so you should be able to extract the correct `*` answer with an added level of nesting.  As to the second comment, a normal `itemize` would not allow stuff before the first `\item`.  But with list of items that is not an issue---however, the numbering will shift by 1 and and item[1] will be that which comes prior to the first item.

Comment: I'm afraid that the sentence  "listofitems can do nested searching, so you should be able to extract the correct * answer with an added level of nesting" is a bit obscure to me :) could you tell me how I can do that? That would be really helpful. Thank you

Comment: @user126154 See my **SUPPLEMENT** in which I answer your question, in full, I hope.

Comment: @user126154 I tweaked the **SUPPLEMENT** in the definition of `\thechoice`.

Comment: @Stefen B. Sgletes just the last question (I hope): does NewEnviron support arguments? like \NewEnviron{2}{itemizesave}{% ...

Comment: @user126154 Yes it does (`\NewEnviron[2]{...}` with square brackets), but you need to be careful how that plays into the environment content.

Comment: I need more helps, could you just have a look at my new question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/642594/i-need-to-expand-a-macro-defined-in-listofitems-package which is basically the same but with a requirement more?