# How to parse an itemized list the way moodle.sty does

Tags: macros, packages, parsing

A simple `moodle.sty` database contains code like that:

```
    \begin{multi}{Name of the question}
     Text of the question
     \item first answer
     \item secon answer
     \item* the starred is the correct answer
     ...
    \end{multi}
```

I need to extract the text, the answers and the correct answer from such databases.

I basically succeeded in doing this by redefining the `multi` environment with the `environ` package and parsing with the help of the `listofitems` package, thank to answers to [that question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/642594/i-need-to-expand-a-macro-defined-in-listofitems-package).

The problem is that questions as well as answers may already make use of `itemize`, `enumerate` etc. In that case each `\item` is interpreted as as the starting of a new answer and the whole procedure crashes. A workaround would be to group texts in braces, but I need to use existing databases and cannot modify them.

Note: Obviously, the style package `moodle.sty` does exactly what I need because it works properly, but I'm not able to understand from the code how it does it. (I'd be happy if I could just copy and paste a portion of moodle.sty or go there and modify some macro to suit my needs, but my knowledge of `TeX` is not that deep).

Note: The packages `moodle.sty` and `getitems.sty` are written by the same person. So, since `moodle.sty` works fine, I guess that `getitems` works better than `listofitems`. Is there an easy way to replace the use of `listofitems` with `getitems` in the answers mentioned above?

Comment: Sounds like rewriting the parser in some other programming language is less hassle.

Answer (score 1):

That's really horrible markup: you won't be able to use lists in the question text.

Anyway, here's a parser.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newcounter{exercise}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentEnvironment{multi}{m +b}
 {
  \par\addvspace{\topsep}\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
  \stepcounter{exercise}
  \textbf{Exercise~\theexercise}~--~#1\par\nobreak
  \moodle_multi:n { #2 }
  \par\addvspace{\topsep}
 }
 {}

\NewDocumentCommand{\showcorrect}{}
 {
  \bool_gset_true:N \g_moodle_multi_correct_bool
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\hidecorrect}{}
 {
  \bool_gset_falsee:N \g_moodle_multi_correct_bool
 }

\bool_new:N \g_moodle_multi_correct_bool
\seq_new:N \l__moodle_multi_text_seq
\tl_new:N \l__moodle_multi_text_tl

\cs_new_protected:Nn \moodle_multi:n
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__moodle_multi_text_seq { \item } { #1 }
  % the first item will contain the question text
  \seq_pop_left:NN \l__moodle_multi_text_seq \l__moodle_multi_text_tl
  \tl_use:N \l__moodle_multi_text_tl
  % now we rebuild the answers
  \begin{enumerate}[label=(\Alph*),nosep,labelsep=0.75em]
  \use:e
   {% add the first \item and put it also between the other items
    \__moodle_multi_item: \seq_use:Nn \l__moodle_multi_text_seq { \__moodle_multi_item: }
   }
  \end{enumerate}
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__moodle_multi_item:
 {
  \item 
  \peek_charcode_remove:NT *
   {% there is an asterisk
    \bool_if:NT \g_moodle_multi_correct_bool { \__moodle_multi_correct: }
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__moodle_multi_correct:
 {
  \makebox[0pt][r]{\makebox[0pt][l]{$^{\scriptscriptstyle*}$}\hspace{\labelsep}}
  \ignorespaces
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{multi}{Name of the question}
  Text of the question
  \item first answer
  \item second answer
  \item* the starred is the correct answer
\end{multi}

\showcorrect

\begin{multi}{Name of the question}
  Text of the question
  \item first answer
  \item second answer
  \item* the starred is the correct answer
\end{multi}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The marker for the correct answers takes up no horizontal space, so if you show it the typesetting is the same as without it.

Can we support lists in the text part? Yes, assuming there aren't in the “answer” part.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newcounter{exercise}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentEnvironment{multi}{m +b}
 {
  \par\addvspace{\topsep}\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
  \stepcounter{exercise}
  \textbf{Exercise~\theexercise}~--~#1\par\nobreak
  \moodle_multi:n { #2 }
  \par\addvspace{\topsep}
 }
 {}

\NewDocumentCommand{\showcorrect}{}
 {
  \bool_gset_true:N \g_moodle_multi_correct_bool
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\hidecorrect}{}
 {
  \bool_gset_falsee:N \g_moodle_multi_correct_bool
 }

\bool_new:N \g_moodle_multi_correct_bool
\seq_new:N \l__moodle_multi_text_seq
\tl_new:N \l__moodle_multi_text_tl
\tl_new:N \l__moodle_multi_moretext_tl
\tl_new:N \l__moodle_multi_answers_tl

\cs_new_protected:Nn \moodle_multi:n
 {
  \regex_split:nnN { \{(enumerate|itemize)\} } { #1 } \l__moodle_multi_text_seq
  \tl_set:Nx \l__moodle_multi_answers_tl { \seq_item:Nn \l__moodle_multi_text_seq { -1 } }
  \tl_set:Nn \l__moodle_multi_text_tl { #1 }
  \regex_replace_once:nnN { (.*)\u{l__moodle_multi_answers_tl} } { \1 } \l__moodle_multi_text_tl
  \seq_set_split:NnV \l__moodle_multi_text_seq { \item } \l__moodle_multi_answers_tl
  % the first item will contain the question text
  \seq_pop_left:NN \l__moodle_multi_text_seq \l__moodle_multi_moretext_tl
  \tl_use:N \l__moodle_multi_text_tl
  \tl_use:N \l__moodle_multi_moretext_tl
  % now we rebuild the answers
  \begin{enumerate}[label=(\Alph*),nosep,labelsep=0.75em]
  \use:e
   {% add the first \item and put it also between the other items
    \__moodle_multi_item: \seq_use:Nn \l__moodle_multi_text_seq { \__moodle_multi_item: }
   }
  \end{enumerate}
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__moodle_multi_item:
 {
  \item 
  \peek_charcode_remove:NT *
   {% there is an asterisk
    \bool_if:NT \g_moodle_multi_correct_bool { \__moodle_multi_correct: }
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__moodle_multi_correct:
 {
  \makebox[0pt][r]{\makebox[0pt][l]{$^{\scriptscriptstyle*}$}\hspace{\labelsep}}
  \ignorespaces
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{multi}{Name of the question}
  Text of the question
  \begin{itemize}
  \item a
  \item b
  \end{itemize}
  More text
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item a
  \item b
  \end{enumerate}
  More text
  \item first answer
  \item second answer
  \item* the starred is the correct answer
\end{multi}

\showcorrect

\begin{multi}{Name of the question}
  Text of the question
  \item first answer
  \item second answer
  \item* the starred is the correct answer
\end{multi}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: well, the presence of lists in text of questions is exactly the problem I need to solve...

Comment: @user126154 That's why I said it's horrible markup. The answers in the `multi` environment should be marked as `\answer` or whatever command so long as it's not `\item`.

Comment: @user126154 I added code to support `enumerate` and `itemize` in the upper part.